# Capturing variable xpath in selenium IDE

Tags: variables, xpath, selenium, ide

Am trying to capture a element (delete button in **gmail**) which has variable xpath.

The xpath is something like this-

```
//*[@id=':rr']/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]
```

can somebody kindly help?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is where the IDE falls behind and it's for good reason. It, along with other 'XPath-ified' (e.g using the 'XPath' right-click option in Firebug) tools will only take a *guess* at where something is located in the DOM.

In that, I mean it's going to walk down the tree and see where it is, in relation to the other elements, i.e it'll walk down one set of `tr` elements, and know there are 7 of them, therefore it'll know that the first one can be accessed using `[1]`, then the next one can be accessed using `[2]` etc etc...

It doesn't, or really can't, know what is *unique* enough for you to use. That's why it's down to you to figure it out.

As for Gmail specifically, I would suggest you either fall back to Gmail's basic mode - so the markup will be easier to deal with or stop completely and use a particular set of API's in whatever language you are using to deal *direct* with the mailboxes in that account.

Though, if you do this, you'll need to dump the IDE altogether - essentially this is beyond the IDE and is a logical thing you need to decide yourself. The IDE is not designed for this.

Though, a tip would be see what's *near* the delete button. Is there a static element, that has the same attributes all the time, near it? You can get *that* element, and walk through to the DOM to your 'delete button'.